# Local custom cordova plugin installation

Tags: cordova-plugins

i created a simple cordova plugin (toast popup) for testing purposes.

The problem comes when i want to add it into a Cordova App to test my plugin : i use `cordova plugin add *path_of_plugin*` while i am inside the cordova app where i want to test the plugin.

Screenshot :
[image: Screenshot]
*(Red : folder of cordova app / Blue : path to my custom cordova plugin)*

What am i doing wrong ?

**EDIT :** tried `..\cordova-plugin-toast` as path of the plugin, stil same errors and not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution, the path for the plugin which was in the same folder as the app is : `..\name_of_plugin`

so navigate to your cordova project then :

```
cordova plugin add ..\name_of_plugin
```

Comment: I used `./path/plugin_folder`: a single `.` means "same folder", while `..` means "go to upper directory" (and didn't work ;)).